# Unable to trigger REST API to add records into MySQL DB

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, postman

I am facing issues while inserting data to MYSQL using Node.JS and Postman

I have created 3 files - db.js, server_db.js, server.js. Server.JS is main file which gets called when we perform GET/POST. I am not able to insert any records in MYSQL DB. I am following Promise code - reject/response here.

1. db.js-

   `var mysql = require("mysql");
   var db_config ={
   host : '127.0.0.1',
   user : 'root',
   password : '*****',
   database : 'webapp'
   };
   var connection;
   console.log("inside db.js 1")
   connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
   connection.connect(function(err){
   if(err) throw err
   console.log('You are now connected..');
   });
   module.exports = connection;`

server_db.js
(This file contains the SQL query to be triggered and used Promises here to resolve and reject)

```
var db = require('../db.js');
save_user_information = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
db.query('INSERT INTO lottery_information SET ?',data,function(err,results,fiels){
if(err){
reject('could not insert into lottery information');
}
resolve('Successful');
});
});
module_exports = {save_user_information};
```

Server.js

From where we are calling the API

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const save_user_information = require('./models/server_db');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/', async function(req, res){
var email = req.body.email;
var amount = req.body.amount;
if(amount <= 1){
return_info = {};
return_info.error = true;
return_info.message = "The amount should be greater than 1";
return res.send(return_info);
}
var result = await save_user_information({"amount" : amount, "email" : email});
res.send(result);
});
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Error I am receiving -

```
(node:17568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: save_user_information is not a function
at C:\GIT\Web2.0\server.js:41:23
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
at invokeCallback (C:\GIT\Web2.0\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
(node:17568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17568) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Thus it seems "save_user_information" is not considering as function.

Can you please advise where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First, to export a module you have to use a dot, not an underscore.
Then, as you are exporting a named module, you should import it as named module.

Comment: Thanks Domeika. I made the changes with module.exports and imported it but still the same error i am receiving.
const save_user_information = require('./models/server_db');

Comment: If you export it like - module.exports = { save_user_information }, then you have to import it like - const { save_user_information } = require(...)

Comment: Thanks Domeika. I have used import like this only
const {save_user_information} = require('./models/server_db');
but still error persists in the code. Please advise

Comment: Please update the wuestion with the code and errors you have now after making the changes.

Comment: And also, in server_db.js file, define the function, using const or var, what you prefer

Comment: Hi Domeika, Please find the source code used in "Answer" section

Comment: can you please advise what code needs to be added in server_db.js file.

console.log('inside server_db.js 1');
var db = require('../db.js');
save_user_information = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  db.query('INSERT INTO lottery_information SET ?',data,function(err,results,fiels){
    if(err){
      reject('could not insert into lottery information');
    }
    resolve('Successful');
  });
});

Comment: I will edit your answer, try copying it into your files.

Comment: Hi. I changed the save_user_information to function and now it is working fine without any issue.Thanks once again. It was a small mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

db.js -
This file has the mysql connection parameters

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var db_config ={
  host : '127.0.0.1',
  user : 'root',
  password : '****',
  database : 'webapp'
};

var connection;
console.log("inside db.js 1")
connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
connection.connect(function(err){
  if(err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected..');
});
```

server_db.js
this has query parameters

```
console.log('inside server_db.js 1');
var db = require('../db.js');
var save_user_information = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  db.query('INSERT INTO lottery_information SET ?',data,function(err,results,fiels){
    if(err){
      reject('could not insert into lottery information');
    }
    resolve('Successful');
  });
});
console.log('inside server_db.js 2');
module.exports = {save_user_information};
```

sever.js -
this is the main file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const {save_user_information} = require('./models/server_db');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/', async function(req, res){
  var email = req.body.email;
  var amount = req.body.amount;

if(amount <= 1){
  return_info = {};
  return_info.error = true;
  return_info.message = "The amount should be greater than 1";
  return res.send(return_info);
}

  var result = await  save_user_information({"amount" : amount, "email" : email});
  res.send(result);

  //res.send({"amount" : amount, "email" : email});

});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

You have to define variable.